# Comparing multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

I have 4 tables with the same structure.
This 4 tables are generated from another one, the main table.

- Main table  -> A (10 000 rows)

  - table 1 -> a1 (2 000 rows)
  - table 2 -> a2 (3 000 rows)
  - table 3 -> a3 (4 000 rows)
  - table 4 -> a4 (1 000 rows)

It's supposed that 4 generated tables are disjoint, and their sum is equal to table A.

But i need to confirm this.

**My question:** How i compare this 4 tables, to see if they have any id in common?

I know that i can build a lot of querys to inner join a1 with a2, a1 with a3 and so on.

But i think that should be another better way.

Comment: what is wrong with writing an inner join on id between all of the tables?

Comment: because an inner join find all ID that are common between all four tables. But what i want is not that. I want to know if a particular ID appears in more than one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just `union all` together all the ids from each table, `group by` each, and check whether any have counts more than one

```
select count(*) from (
select id from table1 union all
select id from table2 union all
select id from table3 union all
select id from table4) group by id having count(*)>1
```

If any id occurs more than once, it will show up in the results of this query.

Comment: thank you! it works very well, and it's simple. to work with mysql i only need to add an alias to the derived table.